# Nginx/Apache serving wrong website

Tags: django, apache, nginx, wsgi

I have nginx as a reverse proxy to apache serving static files for django sites. I have 3 django sites on the server that are working (and have been working for over a year now) but when I try to add a new one either nginx or apache is serving one of the ones that already exist.

For example site A.com & B.com are already on the server. I am attempting to add C.com. I copied over the nginx/apache config files, linked them properly and changed the settings in them properly, restarted nginx & apache sucessfully with no errors but when I try to go to C.com it loads A.com! The DNS has been confirmed as being accurate by Rackspace. I have looked in the log files with no obvious luck. I am assuming this is apache since it is actually rendering the django code for A.com or could nginx be be giving apache the wrong directive?

Also I attempted to unlink one of the working sites that was pointed to the new django code ("C.com", and working!) and then relink (add to sites-enabled) in both nginx & apache and it too now will not work! It just redirects or defaults to A.com.

I've been digging around google with no luck other than apache/nginx defaults but nothing on how to fix this! Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Here are example nginx & apache config files:

nginx

```
server {

    listen 111.111.111.111:80;
    server_name mynewdomain.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 111.111.111.111:80;
    server_name www.mynewdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
    location /media {
        root /home/django/mynewdomain;
        expires 24h;
    }
}
```

apache:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName www.mynewdomain.com
    ServerAlias mynewdomain.com *.mynewdomain.com

    <Directory /home/django/mynewdomain/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Loglevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mynewdomain.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mynewdomain.com.error.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess mynewdomain.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup mynewdomain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/mynewdomain/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line like this in your nginx config, you can place it anywhere in the `server` block:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```